# How can I find the position of a number in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a nested list:

`grades = [[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[8,9,5]]`

Assume these are the grades of 3 students for 3 different classes, how can I get the following:

class: 1, student: 1, grade: 2 
class: 1, student: 2, grade: 3 
class: 1, student: 3, grade: 4 
class: 2, student: 1, grade: 4 
class: 2, student: 2, grade: 5 
...

I can already show the class and grade, but how do I find the index of the students in a nested list?

Comment: Also it is good share your code for printing class and grade, so that we have have the present state of your code and can help you better

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate()` + nested for-loops:

```py
grades = [[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 5]]

for i, g in enumerate(grades, 1):
    for ii, v in enumerate(g, 1):
        print(f"class: {i}, student: {ii}, grade: {v}")
```

Prints:

```
class: 1, student: 1, grade: 2
class: 1, student: 2, grade: 3
class: 1, student: 3, grade: 4
class: 2, student: 1, grade: 4
class: 2, student: 2, grade: 5
class: 2, student: 3, grade: 6
class: 3, student: 1, grade: 8
class: 3, student: 2, grade: 9
class: 3, student: 3, grade: 5
```